# Antlr4: Nested if-then-else in input requires a statement to parse correctly

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have simplified my grammar and am testing it in http://lab.antlr.org/. It works for

```
// if column not exists CURRENTSCHEMA.TABLE_EXISTS.NO_SUCH_COLUMN
  // if column not exists CURRENTSCHEMA.TABLE_EXISTS.NO_SUCH_COLUMN
      alter table TABLE_EXISTS add column (NO_SUCH_COLUMN decimal(5,4));
  // end if
  xyz;   <-------- required! Why???
// end if
```

NOTE: there must be a NL char after the last `// end if`, else the parsing does not work at all. How to fix that is a separate question. When I add to the line comment a (NL | EOF) as termination sequence it complains about missing a NL.

but if I remove that `xyz;` (I call that a statement) then it does not. It looks as if each if-then-else must have at least one statement.
However I have defined a statement as either a text with semicolon or a line comment and a line comment with `// if ... // end if` is considered a directive.

With the `xyz;` the tree is the expected, a line comment of type directive with a statement which has another line comment with directive. Without the `xyz` is is a line comment with directive and within is a regular line comment and a statement.

```
statement : 
  trailing
  | linecomment
  | text* ';' (NL | WS)* ;
```

Can anybody spot my mistake? I have checked the ordering, the length of the tokens but obviously I am missing something essential or I am simply blind.

This is how it should look like, two nested directive nodes.
[image]

Complete grammar file:

```
grammar Sqlscripts;
options { caseInsensitive = true; }

LINE_COMMENT_START: '//' ;
WS: [ \t\r\f]+ ;
NL: '\r\n' | 'r' | '\n' ;

OBJECT: 'OBJECT' ;
COLUMN: 'COLUMN' ;
END: 'END' ;
IF: 'IF' ;
SEMI: ';' ;
NOT: 'NOT' ;
DOT: '.' ;
COMMA: ',' ;
EXISTS: 'EXISTS' ;
WORD: ([A-Z_0-9!#$%&+:<>=?*@{}] 
  | '\\' 
  | ']' | '[' | '-')+ ;


trailing:
  WS* NL ;

identifier:
  WORD DOT WORD (DOT WORD)* ;

directive:
  WS* directivecondition
  statement*
  directiveend ;

directivecondition:
  IF WS*
  (OBJECT | COLUMN ) WS*
  (NOT WS*)? EXISTS WS+
  identifier trailing ;

directiveend:
  LINE_COMMENT_START WS* END WS+
  IF trailing ;

linecomment:
  LINE_COMMENT_START
  (directive | (~(NL)* NL))  ;

text:
  WORD
  | identifier
  | OBJECT
  | COLUMN
  | paramclause
  | NOT
  | EXISTS
  | trailing
  | linecomment
  | WS+
  ;

// A statement is either a command terminated
statement : 
  trailing
  | linecomment
  | text* ';' (NL | WS)* ;

paramclause:
  '(' param_list ')' ;
  
param_list:
  text+ (COMMA text*)* ;

script:
  statement* (NL | WS)* EOF;
```

Comment: It is not a directive, just a regular line comment, in your screen shot.

Comment: Ah, right, thought the parse wasn't successful without the `xyz;`, but it's not in the right structure.

Comment: I think the screenshot you added was a result of your normal grammar. The simplified grammar produces pretty much the same parse trees with or without the `xyz;`

Comment: Thanks for your time, really appreciate your willingness to help. I just tried again, started a new lab.antlr.org session, deleted the lexer contents, pasted the parser into the parser rules and copied the sample, with and without line 5. There I noticed that the parsing produces an error when the last line does not have a trailing\n. This way I can reproduce it.